# PERIODICALLY Error: zend_mm_heap corrupted

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle

**Description**: PERIODICALLY when adding a file through the API, the server crashes with the error in /var/log/httpd/error_log: zend_mm_heap corrupted.
This happens sometimes, then itself begins to work normally. Ie file is normally loaded, then it ceases to be loaded. Although at this time the other can be loaded normally.

I use API /api/providers/sonata.media.provider.file/media

The provider of the file system: sonata.media.filesystem.ftp

Development environment: no matter dev / prod

---

Composer:

- sonata-project/media-bundle: "2.3.x-dev"
- knplabs/gaufrette: >=0.1.4

apache+mod_php:

- httpd-2.2.15-47.el6.centos.x86_64
- httpd-itk-2.2.22-7.el6.x86_64
- php55w-5.5.30-2.w6.x86_64

Other:

- zend.enable_gc = Off
- opcache.fast_shutdown = Off
- USE_ZEND_ALLOC = 0

---

Issue: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/issues/866

Answer (score 0):

Same issues with similar Symfony 3 with media bundle setup.

```
php_flag opcache.enable Off
```

Disabling opcache in .htaccess / php.ini solved the problem.